# Reprinting column but changes don't stick when working with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to use regex to remove the `$` signs, `,` and turn the columns into floats.

```
df[[cols]].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)
```

When I check my work and see if the changes stick, I still get `$` and `,`.

Is there an `inplace=True` parameter or something?

Comment: The docs for `replace`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html . Yes, there is an `inplace` parameter.

Comment: need assign it back `df[[cols]]=df[[cols]].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df[col].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace('$', ''))
```

or

```
df[col].apply(lambda x: x.replace('$', '')).astype(float)
```